# Set a vector to warp upon scaling

Tags: vector, resize

my knowledge of Illustrator is very limited so bear with me.

I've got a vector logo that will be applied to soda bottles of all different widths, and would like to make this vector bend and or curve upon pulling an anchor so that it can be easily wrapped around any bottle. For instance, pulling the anchor on the right wraps the right end of the logo to the back so that it is no longer visible and vice versa with the left anchor.

It will be used on photographs of people who are holding the soda bottles at all different angles, therefore, the entire logo is not always visible depending on the angle of the shot. I hope I explained this well! Very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going to place the logo over photographs you got it wrong from the first four words when you suggested you will use Illustrator for this task.

You can't achieve a satisfying result in Illustrator since it wasn't created for this task, what you are looking for is Photoshop.

> You open your image in Photoshop, import your logo from Illustrator
>   and use the Transform tools (basically ***Distort*** |
>   ***Perspective*** | ***Wrap***) to position your logo.

[image]

> After you are satisfied with the positioning you use all kinds of
>   ***blending modes***, ***hue*** | ***levels*** | ***brightness*** | ***contrast*** | ***blur*** to make it blend in your scenario.

[image]

> Sometimes all the above won't be enough and you will have to improve
>   your logo with a ***texture*** | ***noise*** overlay for it to look
>   genuine.

[image]

*And I did all the above in a couple of minutes, imagine what you can do in an hour where you put all your attention into those details.*

Comment: Hey Alin, thanks for your reply! Now that you mention it, I see what I was attempting would not work in Photoshop. However, I would still like to know how to create the effect in Illustrator.

Comment: @user3869626 No matter what you do you will never get the same effect from Illustrator since it doesn't have the tools/it wasn't created for this...I can't even imagine the amount of steps it would require to get a somewhat decent looking effect in Illustrator...sorry, you can wait for some other answers but don't get your hopes up.

Comment: You *can* do the same transform/distort effects in Illustrator, and you can map artwork to a 3D object in Illustrator which could possibly work better (although you can do that in Photoshop too), but if these are being added to photographs you are better off doing this in Photoshop. If you did do do the initial effect in Illustrator you would need to take it in to Photoshop at some point.

Comment: @CAI I didn't say you can't do some of the things in Illustrator, I said you can't get the same final result in Illustrator and distorting the logo in AI and then dragging it to PS is counterproductive since you would have to open and edit it in AI again if adjustments were needed.

Comment: @Alin no I know, I agree with you. My comment was more directed at OP. I just said you *can* do it in Illustrator, but would be better off doing in Photoshop.

Comment: @CAI Unfortunately he is looking for a way to do it all in AI and...well, you know. :( Thanks and have a nice evening. C'ya tomorrow.